# How to auto update slice range after every operation on it

Tags: rust

I need to extract some of the GPS data that I have received. The data is stored in an `[u8; 1024]` array. I wanted to know is there a way to update a slice range automatically after each extraction
`$GNGGA,062735.00,3150.788156,N,11711.922383,E,1,12,2.0,90.0,M,,M,,*55`

This is a sample code

```
// below functionality doesn't work
fn get_string_token(buff: &[u8], delimiter: u8) -> Result<String, ()> {
    let start_index = 0usize;
    let end_index;
    match buff.iter().position(|ch| *ch == delimiter) {
        Some(index) => end_index = index,
        None => return Err(()),
    }

    let token;
    if end_index - start_index > 1 {
        token = String::from_utf8_lossy(&buff[start_index..end_index]).to_string();
        return Ok(token);
    }
    
    Err(())
}

fn extract_data(buff: &[u8]) {
    let mut token = get_string_token(buff, ',' as u8); // also would like to know how to update the slice range after each extraction
    token = get_string_token(buff, ',' as u8); // also would like to know how to update the slice range after each extraction
    token = get_string_token(buff, ',' as u8); // also would like to know how to update the slice range after each extraction
    // ...
}

fn main() {
    let mut buff: [u8; 1024] = [0; 1024];
    extract_data(&buff[7..]);
}
```

Comment: Either return the "new" range, or take an `&mut &[...]` such that you can "advance" the inner range by reslicing it. You could also use ` `Cursor`, that is used to wrap a slice (or vec) in order to make read/writeable. As such you can read from the cursor and it'll update the internal position automatically.

Comment: You can use `std::io::Write` and friends here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading your `get_string_token` function, it looks like you want to get the column values from a line of a CSV. A much easier way to do this is to use iterators instead of slice manipulation:

```rust
fn extract_data(input: &[u8]) {
    let mut it = input
        .split(|&elem| elem == b',')           // iterate over comma-separated chunks
        .filter(|slice| !slice.is_empty())     // skip empty slices
        .map(|s| String::from_utf8_lossy(s));  // convert to String
        
    let first_column = it.next().unwrap();
    let second_column = it.next().unwrap();
    // etc.
}
```

---

Another method that's closer to your original code is to use `split_at`:

```rust
fn get_string_token(input: &mut &[u8]) -> Option<String> {
    if input.is_empty() {
        return None;
    }

    let idx = match input.iter().position(|&u| u == b',') {
        Some(i) => i,
        None => {
            // The last column isn't terminated by a comma.
            *input = &[];
            return Some(String::from_utf8_lossy(input).into());
        }
    };

    // Turns "abc,def,ghi" into ("abc",",def,ghi").
    let (front, back) = input.split_at(idx);

    // Update the slice, stripping the comma.
    *input = &back[1..];

    Some(String::from_utf8_lossy(front).into())
}


fn extract_data(mut input: &[u8]) -> Vec<String> {
    let first = get_string_token(&mut input).unwrap();
    let second = get_string_token(&mut input).unwrap();
    // etc.
}
```

This ends up being quite a bit more verbose, even without handling empty columns.